# Linq Query Returns Records Including Blank String Data

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I created a query to filter selected days from dataset, for exmaple, filter string is Day="M, W", my table records contains a column named DAYS_OFFERED. The data can be M, W, MW, MWF, T, R, or "" etc. I need to retrieve all records contain M, W, MW or MWF. Now my query returns results including blank string data. What is the problem in my query below:

```
var Courses= db.myTable;

if (Day != null)
{
   string items = Day.Split(',').ToString();
   Courses = Courses.Where(a => items.Contains(a.DAYS_OFFERED) || items.Replace(",",  string.Empty).Contains(a.DAYS_OFFERED));

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use Contains, a string array is ideal. The result of Day.Split(',') is a string array, but you convert it back to a string by calling .ToString().

If you want to retrieve all records that contain M, W, MW or MWF as you say in the question (so you don't need the filter string), you can do this:

```
string[] itemsIWant = {"M", "W", "MW",  "MWF"}; 
var myCourses = Courses.Where(a => itemsIWant.Contains(a.DAYS_OFFERED));
```

If you are going to use the filter string in the Contains, remove any unwanted items such as empty strings beforehand:

```
string[] items = Day.Split(',').Where(str => str != "").ToArray();
var filteredCourses = Courses.Where(a => items.Contains(a.DAYS_OFFERED));
```